Chrome ignores sans-serif font option from CSS stylesheet
I want for Chrome browser to use the San-serif option in chrome://settings/fonts. I have the font below and sans-serif as fallback, but it uses the Standard font in Chrome settings not the Sans-serif font option. How do I force Chrome to use Sans-serif option from the CSS below:
body { font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; }
I tried sans-serif as fallback

Did you check you dev-tool for any given error or what font is being used?

What happens if you leave out the Poppins and ask for sans serif only?

do you have the poppin's font downloaded?
poppins is not normally a font that is included with windows or mac it is either download or imported,
go to google fonts and select poppins and its weight and after copy the url it gives you to link the font to index.html(main file name).
so you need to link the font url with it.

But the code shown says to default to sans-serif should Poppins not be available so I don't understand how this answer helps.
